# filter date from a partiicular column (from the last 3rd column) of a csv file. Also if the last 3rd column is empty then print lines

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, gawk

Input csv file is

```
23,54,one,tree,56,23,7/20/2017 17:00,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,23,7/20/2017 17:00,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,23,7/21/2017 17:00,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,23,7/30/2017 17:00,iii,89
```

**Need shell command to get current date** in format `7/20/2017` and then filter using the same date in a csv file from the last third column (column should not be detected from first or starting since comma varies and hence should be from last 3rd)

Comment: using command DATE=`date +%m/%d/%Y` got today's in correct format as 10/25/2017

Comment: Need only to filter DATE variable from last 3rd column of Input csv file

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you start using ISO8601 date format: YYYY-MM-DD. It's completely unambiguous, plus it sorts the same lexically and chronologically. Some systems provide `date +%F` as a shorthand for `date +%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Added a requirement in a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v "today=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y" | sed 's/^0//')" '$(NF-2) ~ "^"today' file
```

Not happy about using sed, read the date man page more closely:

```
awk -F, -v "today=$(date "+%-m/%d/%Y")" '$(NF-2) ~ "^"today' file
# .........................^^^
```

---

If the 3rd last column is empty or if it is "today"

```
awk -F, -v "today=$(date "+%-m/%d/%Y")" '$(NF-2) == "" || $(NF-2) ~ "^"today' file
```

Comment: Do you understand how it works?

Comment: yeah..today's date format is stored in today variable and then NR from last 3 column filters the date.

Comment: if from the last  3rd column is empty then it can redirected to another file ?

Comment: Please update your requirements in your question

Comment: not able to update the question

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1):

With single GNU **awk** process:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{ d=strftime("%-m/%d/%Y", systime()) }
          $(NF-2)~/^[[:space:]]*$/{ print > "empty_dates.txt" }$(NF-2)~d' file
```

- `$(NF-2)~/^[[:space:]]*$/{ print > "empty_dates.txt" }` - if the 3rd field (at the end) is empty - print the line into file `empty_dates.txt` (you may specify the filename which you like)

Comment: awk -F',' 'BEGIN{ d=strftime("%m/%d/%Y", systime()) }$(NF-2) ~ d' file command only print lines if last 3rd column is empty ?

Comment: @user8554534, now you have a complete solution, see my update

Comment: only recommendation: use `"%-m` to strip the leading zero from the month.

Comment: @glennjackman, you have my update

Comment: and you have my vote ;)